# Books about a broad introduction of philosophy

Tags: reference-request, history-of-philosophy

I am a graduate student of Informatics. 
Studying mathematical logic I've just started discovering it connection to philosophy. Following this way I started reading something about old and modern philosopher. My first source of information is internet, especially Wikipedia, but I am meeting a lots of difficulties because of the use of terms  I don't know the meaning.

So, I want to ask you  a suggestion of a minimal set of books to read in order to get the main concepts related to philosophy. 
I am mainly interested in the explanation of the meaning of the more general terms ( e.g. judgment, subject, object, extension, ecc.. )
I am also interested about a pan on the thoughts of the main philosopher.

Thank you.

Comment: Hold off on the books and instead check out the introductory courses over at http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/linguistics-and-philosophy/index.htm , specifically [Problems of Philosophy](http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/linguistics-and-philosophy/24-00-problems-in-philosophy-fall-2010/)

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a book that explains the terms and fundamental concepts well, I have only one recommendation: [The Philosopher's Toolkit](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1405190183) and by extension [The Ethics Toolkit](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1405132310). It explains all the important terms and concepts in a concise way. I've recommended this book to many people who felt they weren't quite ready to start reading philosophy and they all felt this book helped tremendously.